# Grey overlay in the middle of my GUI - TKinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm having trouble to understand why there is a grey row in my GUI. It's like a overlay, you can write "behind" it but it's is bothering me. Anyone any idea where it comes from?

I'm trying out classes for the first time, when I write the code without classes the problem doesn't occur.

Code:

```
class LabelInput(tk.Frame):  
 
    def __init__(self, parent, label, var, input_class=ttk.Entry,input_args=None, label_args=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        input_args = input_args or {}
        label_args = label_args or {}
        self.variable = var
        self.variable.label_widget = self

        if input_class in (ttk.Checkbutton, ttk.Button):
            input_args["text"] = label
        else:
            self.label = ttk.Label(self, text=label, **label_args)
            self.label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(tk.W + tk.E))

        if input_class in (ttk.Checkbutton, ttk.Button, ttk.Radiobutton):
            input_args["variable"] = self.variable
        else:
            input_args["textvariable"] = self.variable

        if input_class == ttk.Radiobutton:
            self.input = tk.Frame(self)
            for v in input_args.pop('values', []):
                button = ttk.Radiobutton(self.input, value=v, text=v, **input_args)
                button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, ipadx=10, ipady=2, expand=True, fill='x')
        else:
            self.input = input_class(self, **input_args)

        self.input.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=(tk.W+tk.E))
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    
    def grid(self, sticky=(tk.E + tk.W), **kwargs):
        super().grid(sticky=sticky, **kwargs)
```

Problem:

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: I suspect the problem is in your `def grid`. I will have to test it but this is likely the problem. Delete that function. Please note you do not have to define `grid()` since you are inheriting from tk.Frame as that inherency already pulls in grid.

Comment: Please provided a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) So we can test this code.